# Running Retrospective activities

Tags: remote-access, rally

Does Rally have an interface to support activities during retrospective meeting?

Use Case:
Scrum Master running retroactive for a team which has 7 members and all of them are remote.
He would like to run fish bone activities, how can he do that in Rally.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Retrospective Notes in the Notes field of the Iteration for the Team.